# How to check if a function call is made from my front-end?

Tags: dapps, nft, erc-721, dapp-development, mint

Long story short: I want anyone to be able `mint` an ERC721 token using the `mint` function within my contract **BUT** I also want to do some stuff if the `mint` function gets called from my dApp's front-end. Is there a way to check this and do some stuff in my `mint` function?

My idea: Maybe I can create a signature with my wallet that gets into the mint function if the call is made from my front end. I can (can I?) send this signature along with the transaction made by the user using my front end. But can someone see and copy this signature to use it outside my front end?

Comment: hi @mehmedb, please follow up you have an answer here

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a signature that is generated on your server and delivered through your front-end.

This is a web2 solution and will require a client-server setup.